# How would you normalize and calculate speed for a 2D vector if it was clamped by different speeds in all four directions? (-x, +x, -y, +y)

Tags: math, game-physics

My goal here is to improve the user experience so that the cursor goes where the user would intuitively expect it to when moving the joystick diagonally, whatever that means.

---

Consider a joystick that has a different configured speed for each direction.

e.g. Maybe the joystick has a defect where some directions are too sensitive and some aren't sensitive enough, so you're trying to correct for that. Or maybe you're playing an FPS where you rarely need to look up or down, so you lower the Y-sensitivity.

Here are our max speeds for each direction:

```swift
var map = {
    x: 100,
    y: 200,
}
```

The joystick input gives us a unit vector from `0` to `1`.

Right now the joystick is tilted to the right 25% of the way and tilted up 50% of the way.

```
joystick = (dx: 0.25, dy: -0.50)
```

Sheepishly, I'm not sure where to go from here.

### Edit: I will try @Caderyn's solution:

```js
var speeds = {
    x: 100, // max speed of -100 to 100 on x-axis
    y: 300, // max speed of -300 to 300 on y-axis
}

var joystick = { dx: 2, dy: -3 }
console.log('joystick normalized:', normalize(joystick))

var scalar = Math.sqrt(joystick.dx*joystick.dx / speeds.x*speeds.x + joystick.dy*joystick.dy / speeds.y*speeds.y)
var scalar2 = Math.sqrt(joystick.dx*joystick.dx + joystick.dy*joystick.dy)
console.log('scalar1' , scalar) // length formula that uses max speeds
console.log('scalar2', scalar2) // regular length formula

// normalize using maxspeeds
var normalize1 = { dx: joystick.dx/scalar, dy: joystick.dy/scalar }
console.log('normalize1', normalize1, length(normalize1))

// regular normalize (no maxpseed lookup)
var normalize2 = { dx: joystick.dx/scalar2, dy: joystick.dy/scalar2 }
console.log('normalize2', normalize2, length(normalize2))

function length({dx, dy}) {
    return Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)
}

function normalize(vector) {
    var {dx,dy} = vector
    var len = length(vector)
    return {dx: dx/len, dy: dy/len}
}
```

Am I missing something massive or does this give the same results as regular `vector.len()` and `vector.normalize()` that don't try to integrate the maxspeed data at all?

Comment: is it important to separate left and right and up and down? Because the problem would be easier with a vertical and an horizontal speed only.

Comment: That would be sufficient. Especially since you can only move in one direction on each axis at a time, so all four speeds never apply at the same time.

Comment: then why don't you multiply your y input value with the max vertical speed and your x input value with the horizontal speed ?

Comment: To confirm - you’re given a vector. You want the largest vector pointing in that direction that doesn’t exceed the min/max values in the x or y direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

three solutions :

- You can simply multiply each component of the input vector by it's respective speed
- you can divide the vector itself by sqrt(dx^2/hSpeed^2+dy^2/vSpeed^2)
- you can **multiply** the vector itself by sqrt((dx^2+dy^2)/(dx^2/hSpeed^2+dy^2/vSpeed^2)) or 0 if the input is (0, 0)

the second solution will preserve the vector's direction when the first will tend to pull it in the direction with the greatest max speed. But if the domain of those function is the unit disc, their image will be an ellipse whose radii are the two max speeds

EDIT : the third method does what the second intended to do: if the imput is A, it will return B such that a/b=c/d (the second method was returning C):
[image: 1]

Comment: Thanks. I realize that's my problem with the first solution (what I started with): the greater speed seems to dominate. Though it's hard to know how it *should* feel when each axis has it's own maxSpeed. Your explanation of your second solution sounds good to me, I will try it out.

Comment: okay, I tried to apply your second bullet point, I've updated my question with some work. how come i seem to get the same result normalizing the vector normally, without the maxspeed data?

Comment: yes you're right, I was focused on the vectors with a unit lenght and I forgot the smaller ones. I edited the answer and now it should be better. (the old formula was projecting all the vectors on the ellipse and the new only scale them in a way that only the unit vectors get projected on the ellipse